# Problem with splitting columns with semicolon Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I've been generating the same CSV file every month for a year now and splitting the values by the semicolon successfully every time. However, the columns this time don't split for some reason.
[image: screenshot]

Some of the values split, but the majority don't.
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

I searched but didn't find anyone talking about this problem, and thought of posting here.

Comment: Paste the data as text, not an image, and the power query into your question.

Comment: what does the data look like at the part that is not splitting?